# SQLite query optimization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I'm using this query to fetch places near user.

```
query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT place_index, place_name,  place_category, place_address, place_phone, place_mobile, place_description, place_email, place_website, place_facebookId, place_neighborhood, place_rating, place_lat, place_long, place_is_closed, product_name, distance(place_lat, place_long, '%f', '%f') AS dist FROM (SELECT places.id as place_index, places.name as place_name, places.category as place_category, places.address as place_address, places.phone as place_phone, places.mobile as place_mobile, places.description as place_description, places.email as place_email, places.website as place_website, places.facebookId as place_facebookId, places.neighborhood as place_neighborhood, places.rating as place_rating, places.lat as place_lat, places.long as place_long, places.is_closed as place_is_closed, products.name as product_name FROM places LEFT JOIN products ON products.place_id = places.id UNION SELECT places.id as place_index, places.name as place_name,  places.category as place_category, places.address as place_address, places.phone as place_phone, places.mobile as place_mobile, places.description as place_description, places.email as place_email, places.website as place_website, places.facebookId as place_facebookId, places.neighborhood as place_neighborhood, places.rating as place_rating, places.lat as place_lat, places.long as place_long, places.is_closed as place_is_closed, added_products.name as added_product_name FROM places LEFT JOIN added_products ON added_products.place_id = places.id) WHERE place_is_closed = 0 ", userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Basically I have Select from a Union of Selects with LEFT joins. This query is used in the search mechanism, so it triggers off each time user inputs something into a `UITextField`. It takes an impossibru 1 second to execute and fetch objects, is there a way to optimize it somehow?

-- EDIT

This is the query's text as requested, the formatting parameters are listed above, but I don't think they're an issue:

```
SELECT place_index, 
       place_name, 
       place_category, 
       place_address, 
       place_phone, 
       place_mobile, 
       place_description, 
       place_email, 
       place_website, 
       place_facebookid, 
       place_neighborhood, 
       place_rating, 
       place_lat, 
       place_long, 
       place_is_closed, 
       product_name, 
       Distance(place_lat, place_long, '%f', '%f') AS dist 
FROM   (SELECT places.id           AS place_index, 
               places.name         AS place_name, 
               places.category     AS place_category, 
               places.address      AS place_address, 
               places.phone        AS place_phone, 
               places.mobile       AS place_mobile, 
               places.DESCRIPTION  AS place_description, 
               places.email        AS place_email, 
               places.website      AS place_website, 
               places.facebookid   AS place_facebookid, 
               places.neighborhood AS place_neighborhood, 
               places.rating       AS place_rating, 
               places.lat          AS place_lat, 
               places.long         AS place_long, 
               places.is_closed    AS place_is_closed, 
               products.name       AS product_name 
        FROM   places 
               LEFT JOIN products 
                 ON products.place_id = places.id 
        UNION 
        SELECT places.id           AS place_index, 
               places.name         AS place_name, 
               places.category     AS place_category, 
               places.address      AS place_address, 
               places.phone        AS place_phone, 
               places.mobile       AS place_mobile, 
               places.DESCRIPTION  AS place_description, 
               places.email        AS place_email, 
               places.website      AS place_website, 
               places.facebookid   AS place_facebookid, 
               places.neighborhood AS place_neighborhood, 
               places.rating       AS place_rating, 
               places.lat          AS place_lat, 
               places.long         AS place_long, 
               places.is_closed    AS place_is_closed, 
               added_products.name AS added_product_name 
        FROM   places 
               LEFT JOIN added_products 
                 ON added_products.place_id = places.id) 
WHERE  place_is_closed = 0
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting the query in a way such that we can actually read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the subquery return the only the identity column for the `places` table and add a new JOIN to the table at the top  on the identity column. This should make the subquery calculation lighter.

Comment: Thanks, that increased the speed from 0.7-1.1 sec to 0.3-.06 sec from time to time. Do you have any other useful tips maybe? I'm also using  LIKE compare a lot, is that bad for performance as well?

Comment: @Eugene, well, it depends on the queries. Like is not evil as itself, one should look at. My tip is to read a couple of books on SQL, they give more understanding than a couple of tips.

Comment: it would actually be great to have time to read books, but, alas, in iOS development world there is never such a thing like a spare time. :) Thank you though